MUI table height
I'm experiencing an issue with MUI-X tables. Ideally, I want to have buttons that, when clicked, generate two tables. However, I've noticed that each time I switch between the tables, the last row grid has a delay in adjusting to the correct height, causing a flicker that users can see.
Here's a link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/unruffled-bhaskara-q9syy8
Is there any way to avoid this flicker/ height adjustment issue?
I have tried to adjust the value of getEstimatedRowHeight={() => 400}, getRowHeight={() => "auto"} along with the parent height but didn't seem to work.

I am not sure it will help you or not but you can try this once by adding loader and autoHeight
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState('table1');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleButtonClick = (newTable) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTable(newTable);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 300); // Adjust the delay as needed
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick('table1')}>Show Table 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick('table2')}>Show Table 2</button>
      {loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <DataGrid
          rows={table === 'table1' ? rows1 : rows2}
          columns={columns}
          autoHeight
          rowHeight={50} // Adjust as needed
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


Thank you so much for the suggestions. However, I will have multiple buttons and not sure if adding loading would be the best solution.
